# SharePoint 2013 - Questions while in preview mode

Tags: discussion

As SharePoint 2013 is still in preview mode and may change substantially. Which types of questions are appropriate for SharePoint SE?

The context to my question is installation issues which may not be relevant at the time of RTM, which would mean SharePoint SE has incorrect data.

An example question is here:
[Installing Sharepoint 2013 Windows 7](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41204/installing-sharepoint-2013-preview-on-windows-7)
This answer may be subject to change as SP2013 get closer to RTM.

Another example is an issue with network adapters installing on Win Server 2012: [Installing Sharepoint 2013 preview on Windows Server 2012](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41184/installing-sharepoint-2013-preview-on-windows-server-2012).  This is likely due to still being in preview.

Comment: 2nd Question "Installing Sharepoint 2013 preview on Windows Server 2012" doesn't just have problem with network adapter, if question is being read properly you will know he(I am) asking if its possible to install sharepoint 2013 on Server 2012, I wonder if we wont gonna ask these questions on SE then who are we suppose to ask :| (with due respect)

Comment: With respect, you mention you are having specific issues with installation: "Now having trouble with NETFX35 while installing SQL Server 2012." This is probably due to it being an early preview release, and the accepted answer is that it works for them.

Comment: My question is that the value and validity of these questions may not expand beyond a few days/weeks or may be due to lack of/incorrect documentation.

Comment: yes, but at least I knew it worked for someone then I tried and it worked for me as well, if I wasn't knowing it worked for anyone yet I would had given my hope + that guy told me to use PS image services which I gonna use after work.

Comment: Its SharePoint and its huge I wonder if question about it will be around for weeks, Even tho they say its a beta version and release product can be 100% different but thats nothing more then a statement :)

Comment: 137 views on a single day for that question its helping people getting aware about SO SE and I hope more people will participate/register in future as well

Comment: I agree anything to raise awareness and use of SO SE is great. What I don't want is down the track visitors using answers as assumptions and finding out they are incorrect or not exactly right.  That could hurt SO SE in the long run.

Comment: I guess people are clever enough to know if they get a wrong or miss leading answer by someone, its individuals fault. They cant blame SO SE for that :)

Comment: I don't think they will "blame" SO SE, they just won't return :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these questions are definitely on topic here.

That being said, we should try to avoid questions that are relevant to only a specific moment in time. The inaccurate information could definitely be a problem as time goes on.

I would recommend that once the final product is released, we **edit** these questions and **merge** information from future questions to keep one source of information.

Comment: This was my key concern - "...Questions that are relevant to only a specific moment in time." Thanks for clarifying Kit :)

Answer (score 4):

How about changing the tag 2013 to 2013-preview or something similar to that?

or, at least create a tag specific to the preview version.

Comment: This is a great idea IMO.

Comment: Yeah that will help with the cleanup process once SP2013 goes into RTM

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fair game if people have questions about it. We are not a discussion forum, but if people want to open community wiki type questions I think that's fine as well. Not too much though - we don't want a huge editing job next year getting rid of content that is no longer relevant.

Comment: Inevitably there will be content which will need to be edited post-preview.